# How to do lazy loading with wpf DataGrid Control when scrollviewer reached at bottom?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ScrollViewer Name="svDataGrid" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" >
        <DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"   Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="dgList" Grid.Row="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Azure"
                     CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                     CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                     CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="dgList_MouseDoubleClick"  PreviewKeyDown="dgList_PreviewKeyDown">

        </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: How to..... Usually ends with a question mark!!

Comment: Why do you put a DataGrid into a ScrollViewer? A DataGrid owns it's own set of scrollbars and a ScrollViewer will just mess these up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will probably not accomplish what you want (at least thats my guess, since you don't state what you really want).

A DataGrid does contain it's own Scrollbars, and by putting the DataGrid into a ScrollViewer, you'll tell the DataGrid to go maximum size, no need for scrolling (the ScrollViewer will take care of that). So the grid will load and render all it's contents.

It would be advisable to get rid of the ScrollViewer, so you can use the proper scrolling technique for the DataGrid itself. Then you probably want to look for DataGrid Virtualization (but I'm not sure what you really want to achieve, so it might be something different).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason to use a ScrollViewer with a DataGrid, as @Sam says, the DataGrid has its own Scrollbars.  If your reason is because you want to catch the ScrollChanged event, you can do so by using the attached property on the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged"  ...>
</DataGrid>
```